# How to get the Form result in div?

Tags: html

Hi i have this html code to submit the data to google

```
    <form name="input" action="http://www.google.com" method="get">
    Username: <input type="text" name="user">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

when i type words to search and click submit button,it should go to google.com,it should get the result and that result should be displayed in div..how can i do thar... thanks in advance

Comment: when i type words to search and click submit button,it should go to google.com,it should get the result and that result should be displayed in div.

Answer (score 0):

You can, with some limitations, have the results of form submissions to be displayed inside the current page (containing the form) by using a `target` attribute in the `form` tag. The attribute value should match the value of a `name` attribute in an `iframe` element on the page. You can wrap the `iframe` element inside a `div` element, of course.

However, this won’t work in the given case. First, the form is not a Google search form. To launch a search, the `action` attribute should be e.g. `http://www.google.fi/search`, and the form should contain a field named by Google naming conventions; `q` is the name for a keywords input item. Second, and more seriously, Google just does not let you do that. In HTTP headers, it says [`X-Frame-Options   SAMEORIGIN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header), which means that you cannot get the results inside a frame on a page at your site.

Answer (score -1):

You will have to use javascript for this. Also, use the **Inner Frame** for this. And the code will be something like:

```
 <form name="input" action="html_form_action.asp" method="get">
        Username: <input type="text" name="user">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="function1">
        </form>
    <div id="result">

 <iframe src="http://www.google.com/" border-style:solid;">
 </iframe>

</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function1(){
    var el=document.getElementById("result")
    el.innerHTML="<iframe src=\"http://www.google.com\"></iframe>"
    }
    </script>
```